# Error while compiling for NodeMCU on Arduino IDE on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arduino

I've been trying to link a piece of code with Blynk app using NodeMCU and I am compiling the code on Arduino IDE on Ubuntu. The following is my code:

```
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial


#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>

// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "myAuthToken";

// Your WiFi credentials.
// Set password to "" for open networks.
char ssid[] = "myWifi";
char pass[] = "myPassword";
BlynkTimer timer;
void setup()
{
  // Debug console
  Serial.begin(9600);
  timer.setInterval(1000L, function);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  // You can also specify server:
  //Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass, "blynk-cloud.com", 80);
  //Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass, IPAddress(192,168,1,100), 8080);
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
  timer.run();
}
void function()
{
  int ldrValue=analogRead(A0);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, ldrValue);
}
```

It is showing me an error whenever I try to compile it. The following is the error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Linux), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4M (no SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

fork/exec /home/enlightened/snap/arduino-mhall119/5/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python/3.7.2-post1/python: no such file or directory
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Answer (score 3):

You either need to install Python, or fix(re-link) the file in the Arduino IDE pointing to the Python binary.

Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), type `python` at the prompt, press <kbd>enter</kbd>:

```
~$ python
```

If the terminal suggests installing Python, doing so will probably fix the problem:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python
```

Otherwise, if you see this:

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

It means Python is installed, but you need to fix the symlink in this file:

```
/home/enlightened/snap/arduino-mhall119/5/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python/3.7.2-post1/python
```

to point at the installed Python binary, like so:

```
~$ ln -s /usr/bin/python /home/enlightened/snap/arduino-mhall119/5/.arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python/3.7.2-post1/python
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the `arduino-mhall119` snap. It is broken and deprecated, **you should install the [`arduino`](https://snapcraft.io/arduino) snap instead.** It has support for Python 3.

```sh
snap install arduino
```

If you haven't done so; you should also add your user to the `dailout` group so it can access USB serial devices.

```sh
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

After this, restart your device and run "Arduino IDE".

### Details

Snaps run applications inside of a sandbox so it does not have access to Python of your device. The [`arduino`](https://snapcraft.io/arduino) snap fixes this by bundling Python *inside* of that sandbox.

### Module not found..

If you need additional Python modules which are not yet installed in the snap, you can install them yourself by running `arduino.pip install <packagename>`. This will install the packages inside of the sandbox using pip.